# Quotient space in the book The Large scale structure of space-time

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

On page 79, the author states

> One is thus concerned only with $\mathbf{Z}$ modulo a component parallel to $\mathbf{V}$, i.e. only with the projection of $\mathbf{Z}$ at each point $q$ into the space $Q_q$ consisting of equivalence classes of vectors which differ only by addition of a multiple of $\mathbf{V}$. This space can be represented as the subspace $H_q$ of $T_q$ consisting of vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$.

where $\mathbf{Z}$ is the tangent vector $(\partial/\partial t)_\lambda$ on a family $\lambda (t,s)$ of curves, and $\mathbf{V}$ the timelike tangent vector parameterized by $s$.

How do we formally define this quotient space? I'm not very familiar with the concept of *equivalence classes*, *quotient space*, *isomorphic*, *modulo* and *coset*; only from a linear algebra course I remembered the professor defined that: given two vector spaces $W \le V$, we define $V/W$ the quotient space of $V$ by $W$ to be the set $V/W=\{ x+W\ |\ x\in V \}$. And something about the square bracket $[x]$ being the coset of $V$ with representative $x$.

On page 86, where the author is talking about the null curves

> The second difference is that $Q_q$, the quotient of $T_q$ by $\mathbf{K}$, is not now isomorphic to $H_q$, the subspace of $T_q$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{K}$, since $H_q$ includes the vector $\mathbf{K}$ itself as $g(\mathbf{K},\mathbf{K})=0$. In fact as will be shown below, one is not really interested in the whole of $Q_q$ but only in the subspace $S_q$ consisting of equivalence classes of vectors in $H_q$ which differ only by multiple of $\mathbf{K}$.

where $\mathbf{K}$ is the tangent vector on the null geodesics.

I know that it's not clear how to define a projection of $T_q$ into the subspace $H_q$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{K}$ since $g(\mathbf{K},\mathbf{K})=0$, but I want to understand the concept of quotient space here, and how formally that $Q_q$ is not isomorphic to $H_q$, an from these notions construct a projection operator ${h^a}_b$. What is the subspace $S_q$? These kinds of discussion are all over this chapter 4.

Heuristically (I don't know why) the author used the *pseudo-orthonormal* bases defined on page 87: take $\mathbf{E}_4$ equal to $\mathbf{K}$ and $\mathbf{E}_3$ some other null vector satisfying $g(\mathbf{E}_3,\mathbf{E}_4)=-1$, and $\mathbf{E}_1$ and $\mathbf{E}_2$ to be unit space like vectors, orthogonal to each other and to $\mathbf{E}_3$ and $\mathbf{E}_4$. The following statements are out of my reach

> It can be seen that $\mathbf{E}_1$, $\mathbf{E}_2$ and $\mathbf{E}_4$ constitute a basis for $H_q$ while the projections into $Q_q$ of $\mathbf{E}_1$, $\mathbf{E}_2$ and $\mathbf{E}_3$ form a basis of $Q_q$, and the projections of $\mathbf{E}_1$ and $\mathbf{E}_2$ form a basis of $S_q$. We shall normally not distinguish between a vector $\mathbf{Z}$ and its projection into $Q_q$ or $S_q$. We shall call a basis having the properties of $\mathbf{E}_1$, $\mathbf{E}_2$, $\mathbf{E}_3$, $\mathbf{E}_4$, above, *pseudo-orthonormal*.

The author further concluded that the dual basis $\mathbf{E}^3$ is equal to $-K^ag_{ab}$ and $\mathbf{E}^4$ is $-L^ag_{ab}$. Well, I think then $L_b = -K^a g_{ab} = -K_b$, and $g(\mathbf{E}_3,\mathbf{E}_4)=0$?

I really like to know these geometrical objects as they are so powerful and abstract, which is good. My current reference book is Schutz, *Geometrical methods of mathematical physics*. He touches on these idea on a section about *cohomology theory* (this section is categorized as supplementary topics, and in fact I did not understand a word). Is there any suggestion to a light weighted reference book for a physicist?

Thanks!

Comment: This is unrelated to cohomology.

Comment: A friendly word of advice, OP. If you feel like you're stumbling time and time again in a book, you might not be ready for it. I think Wald's book on GR treats this material more clearly for a beginner. (I will still answer this question when I have time.)

Comment: I believe so. In fact, now I'm only interested in the geodesic congruence and I found it was treated in this book, so I just dig right into it.. I think a good mathematical reference book will help.

Comment: Actually I've found the [lecture notes](http://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/poisson/research/agr.pdf) by Poisson covered the same material in a more detailed manner. But who don't want to read the book by Hawking first? Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H_q$ is indeed a quotient space constructed from $T_q$. We establish the equivalence relation $\mathbf{X}\sim\mathbf{W}$ for $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{W}\in T_q$ if $\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{W}=k\mathbf{V}$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $H_q\cong T_q/\sim$. (In "linear algebra notation," we have $T_q/\sim=T_q/\operatorname{span}\mathbf{V}$.$^1$) To see this more clearly, let $[\mathbf{X}]$ be the equivalence class of $\mathbf{X}$ under $\sim$. Expand $\mathbf{X}$ in the basis $\{\mathbf{E}_1,\mathbf{E}_2,\mathbf{E}_3,\mathbf{V}\}$ as $X^a \mathbf{E}_a$. (We set $\mathbf{E}_4=\mathbf V$ for convenience.) Let $\mathbf W\in [\mathbf X]$, then $\mathbf W=W^a\mathbf E_a$ and 
$$\mathbf X-\mathbf W=(X^4-W^4)\mathbf V+(X^\alpha-W^\alpha)\mathbf E_\alpha=k\mathbf V$$
where $\alpha=1,2,3$. Thus $X^\alpha=W^\alpha$ and $[\mathbf X]$ uniquely determines ${}_\bot \mathbf X:=X^\alpha\mathbf E_\alpha$. As explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243474/fermi-propagated-jacobi-equation-in-the-book-the-large-scale-structure-of-space/243487#243487), ${}_\bot \mathbf X\in H_q.$ Likewise, one can show that $\mathbf X\in H_q$ gives rise to an equivalence class $[\mathbf X]$. Thus the quotient space and the orthogonal subspace are isomorphic.

We will show that $Q_q:=T_q/\operatorname{span}\mathbf K\not\cong H_q$. Note that $H_q:=\{\mathbf{X}\in T_q\mid g(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{K})=0\}$. From the above discussion, it should be clear that $\mathbf K\notin Q_q$. But since $\mathbf K$ is null, $\mathbf K\in H_q$. This cannot happen if $H_q\cong Q_q$.

The space $S_q$ is the set of vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf K$ modulo $\mathbf K$ itself, that is, $S_q=H_q/\operatorname{span}\mathbf K$.

To see that $\mathbf E_1,\mathbf E_2$ and $\mathbf K$ span $H_q$, simply note that $H_q$ is $3$-dimensional and $\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf E_1,\mathbf E_2,\mathbf K\}$ contains only vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf K$ and is $3$-dimensional.

The proof that $S_q=\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf E_1,\mathbf E_2\}$ is identical to the proof in the first paragraph and is left to the reader.

The concept of a dual basis is explained on page 17. We explain why $E^3_a=-K^bg_{ba}$ and leave the reader to verify the rest: $\mathbf{E}^3(\mathbf{E}_3)=E^3_aE^a_3=-K^bg_{ba}L^a=-\langle\mathbf K,\mathbf L\rangle=1=\delta^3{}_3$.

---

$^1$ The span of a single vector $\mathbf X$ is $\{a\mathbf X\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: For $Q_q:=T_q/ \text{span} \mathbf{V}$, we only show that $[\mathbf{X}]$ is uniquely determined by ${}_\bot \mathbf{X}$, where ${}_\bot \mathbf{X} \in H_q$. What do you mean by "Likewise, one can show that $\mathbf{X} \in H_q$ gives rise to an equivalence class $[\mathbf{X}]$"? Isn't it a definition? How do we conclude from this that $H_q \cong Q_q$? Maybe there are other elements in $H_q$ that is not in $Q_q$.

Comment: So, we construct $S_q$ so that $\text{span}\mathbf{K} \notin S_q$. Are $Q_q$ (from $T_q/\text{span}K$) and $S_q$ isomorphic? And what do you mean by the sentence "is uniquely determined by" in the firs part?

Comment: @Henry 1. To show that $H_q\cong Q_q$, show that there exists a map $f:H_q\to Q_q, \mathbf X\mapsto[\mathbf X]$ that is injective and surjective. You should be able to do the careful proof yourself, I've laid most of it out in the post. 2. No, $Q_q$ and $S_q$ are not isomorphic, their dimensions are not equal. 3. I mean that the only information you need for $[\mathbf X]$ is ${}_\bot \mathbf X$ and one ${}_\bot \mathbf X$ generates exactly one equivalence class.

Comment: The elements in $Q_q$ are the equivalent classes $[\mathbf{X}]$. How can we say that $\mathbf{K} \notin Q_q?$. I know that the vectors in $\text{span}\mathbf{K}$ are mapped into zero vector, so...? I think I know the concept, but I cannot state it formally.

Comment: By $\langle\mathbf{K},\mathbf{L}\rangle$ I think you mean $g(\mathbf{K},\mathbf{L})$. Or is it a common practice to denote the  mapped one-form $\mathbf{K} = g(\mathbf{K})$?

Comment: @Henry It's standard to denote the inner product $g(-,-)$ induced on $\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(TM)$ by $\langle-,-\rangle$.

Comment: @Henry Take the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2=\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf i,\mathbf j\}$ and quotient it by $\mathbb R$. Try to convince yourself that $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb R$ contains only the span of the vector $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j\notin \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In two dimensional Cartesian system, take the y axis to be the subspace, then $Q_q = \{ \ldots,[(-1,0)],[(0,0)],[(1,0)],\ldots \} $, where $[(1,0)]=[(1,1)]=\ldots$ are the same equivalent class. Now the element in the one dimensional vector space $Q_q$ are the equivalent classes, what do we mean by $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$?

Comment: @Henry $\mathbf i=(1,0),\mathbf j=(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, they are these two dimensional element. We cannot compare them without a map to the one dimensional quotient space, right? Maybe there were some description of mine above which were wrong.

Comment: @Henry Please see the Wiki article on the quotient of a vector space. The necessary theorem is: if $V=U\oplus W$, then $V/W\cong U$. If you don't understand this,  please ask a question on Math SE.

Comment: Maybe it is the map $f:H_q \rightarrow Q_q$ is only surjective but non-injective, since both zero vector and $\mathbf{K}$ are mapped to the same equivalent classes $[0]$. This is cool stuff, Thanks a lot!!! Your explanation is always so clear and insightful. I will take an algebra course next semester for sure.

Comment: @Henry Uh, note that in the first paragraph, where I'm talking about $f$, $\mathbf K$ has not been introduced yet. I think you're getting things mixed up here.

Comment: I don't get it. By $f$ I mean $f:H_q \rightarrow T_q/\text{span}\mathbf{K}$. And it is not because $\mathbf{K} \notin T_q/\text{span}\mathbf{K}$ that make it not isomorphism, but the map.

Comment: @Henry I never claimed that was an isomorphism. (In fact, quite the opposite.)